# Using Cycles Render, how do I produce a material with a transparent section of the texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

I have tries a bunch of methods using the nodes and various node configurations as explained in a number of other how-tos and tutorials, and every result is the same, no transparency. The alpha layer of my image is either solid black, or solid white, not transparent.

How to I creat a material using nodes with the Cycles Render using a texture image (.png file) which a center area that is transparent (alpha channel).

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/how-do-i-get-transparency-to-work-with-the-principled-bsdf-shader and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39994/transparent-textures-that-allow-light-to-shine-through

Comment: Please read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86315/change-opacity-transparent-image-texture/86348#86348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using mixing transparent node with your material. And that the Transparent node is in the top input of the mix shader.

[image: Blend File Screenshot]

The Blend file I attached is the file the screenshot is from.

[image]