# Atmosphere and alpha chanel

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, transparency

I have 2 planes with a png texture and alpha channel, I also have a atmosphere effect by sun light.

When I see it in rendered viewport shading its ok, but when I really render the composition the area where it is supposed to be totally transparent is not affected by atmosphere:

[image: rendered viewport shading]

[image]

[image: final render]

[image]

Comment: Related: [Transparent textures that allow light to shine through](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39994/transparent-textures-that-allow-light-to-shine-through/39995#39995)

Comment: How can i do that in blender render?