# Applying an image with an alpha mask to a plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders, transparency

I want to place a png file floating over my 3D model's face to create eyes. I've placed the image on a plane that I've UV unwrapped.
[image]
The problem I have is that when I render the image, you can see straight through his head.
[image]
How can I achieve the desired result?

I'm new to blender so go easy :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89074/transparent-png-over-a-base-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39994/transparent-textures-that-allow-light-to-shine-through

Comment: Thanks for the kind introduction to your community. I have followed the node setup tutorials, which all seem to do it the same way. There's something Im doing wrong and I just cant see it

Comment: What does it look like when you actually render, not just in the material view? This just looks like bad transparency sorting in the glsl viewport.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a difference between rendering and using the rendering viewport! After rendering it looks like it works thanks @Sazerac

Answer (score 1):

This looks like bad alpha sorting in the viewport. It should be fine in the rendered view.

Essentially, Blender's old GLSL viewport has pretty mixed results with drawing transparency. this should be fixed in the new 2.8 Eevee based viewport.